# Get inputs value in dynamic list with Java script

Tags: javascript, input, html-lists

I want to create a form where I can add or delete inputs.

I will use it to send requests to my web service.
I wish I could add as many parameters as I want.

Button add to add two inputs and the delete button
Delete button to delete 2 inputs and button

Screen

[image: picture]

I choose to put the this fields in an dynamic list.

HTML

```
<ul class="fields" id="fields">
</ul>
<input type="button" value="ADD" name="addField" id="addField" class="addField">
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var buttonAddField = document.getElementById('addField');
        var fields = document.getElementById('fields');

        //add fields and delete fields
        buttonAddField.addEventListener('click', function () {

            var li = document.createElement('li');

            var buttonDelete = document.createElement('button');
            buttonDelete.addEventListener('click', function () {
                fields.removeChild(li);

            });
            buttonDelete.appendChild(document.createTextNode("DELETE"));

            var inputName = document.createElement("input");
            inputName.type = "text";



            var inputValue = document.createElement("input");
            inputValue.type = "text";


            li.appendChild(inputName);
            li.appendChild(inputValue);
            li.appendChild(buttonDelete);

            fields.appendChild(li);

        });
</script>
```

When I want to send my request I want to get key/value in my list.

I had this idea :

```
var data = new FormData();

var items = fields.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log(items[i]);
}
```

It returns

```
 <li>...</li>
```

How to get key/value ?

Answer (score 0):

I found where was the problem :
Google Chrome send me : `<li>...</li>` because object was too big.

Here is my solution :

```
var items = fields.getElementsByTagName('li');

     for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
             console.log(items[i].childNodes[0].value);
             console.log(items[i].childNodes[1].value);
     }
```

Comment: It's not because it was "too big". An `li` element is… well, an Element. Not a string. Coercing it into a string (which `console.log` doesn't do; you can expand that `…` part) will not magically extract the text inside it (there is the `textContent` property for that) and actually produces different results in different browsers.